# Where should I pack my electronic Tesla Coil?

Tags: hand-luggage, electronic-items, prohibited-items

I'm a coiler; I make Tesla Coils. I have various sizes. I would like to carry it on if possible because they are a little fragile. It will fit size restrictions. I hope I can at least check it.

Comment: What country / countries are you traveling in?  And, I assume you are talking about air travel?